# Mapview Popup Graph Appear on Hover?

Tags: r, r-mapview

Is there a way to make popup graphs appear on hover (rather than click) in Mapview? Alternatively, is it possible for the graphs to appear open by default? Rather than produce my own reproducible example, I would defer to the [example given with the R Mapview documentation](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/articles/articles/mapview_04-popups.html#graph-popups-1).

I am fairly new to R and Mapview so any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just pushed an update to package **leafpop** which provides the popup functionality used in **mapview**. This should provide what you want (at least partly - as `mapview()` will still need to be updated). This allows you to now specify `tooltip = TRUE` in `addPopupImages` (in `addPopupGraphs` via `...`). Note that it is encouraged to use `addPopup*` functions over the classic `popup*` functions because they also work in non-interactive setting, e.g. when saving a map locally.

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(lattice)
library(leafpop)

pt = data.frame(x = 174.764474, y = -36.877245)
pt = st_as_sf(pt, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

p2 = levelplot(t(volcano), col.regions = terrain.colors(100))

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = pt, group = "pt") %>%
  addPopupGraphs(
    list(p2)
    , group = "pt"
    , width = 300
    , height = 400
    , tooltip = TRUE
  )
```

Not sure when and how to integrate this into `mapview()` as this is a bit more complicated than the classic `popup*` functions (because we need to know something about the map object we create with mapview before we create it...). In any case, I hope this is at least partly useful and helps resolve your issue.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you! Really appreciate your taking the time to push an update to the package.

Comment: My pleasure, this is a great use-case that should be supported!